Edit Fields are not replacing old values?
Why is my edit function failing to save the new text and date values? Currently, the function displays the edit modal but fails to submit updated text if it's blank. Despite updating the object in the array and rendering it in the DOM, it seems to perceive the new values as blank, leading to the failure in saving them. What might be causing this issue?
You can see the dummy code via code pen:
CodePen-Edit task
This is what is happening:

A new task is created.
Click the edit button.
edited form appears.
update new text.
update new date.
click the submit button.
New values show blank in the task object in the array.
New task and date values show blank when DOM is updated.

function editTask(id) {
  let taskIndex = taskArray.findIndex((task) => task.id === id);
  let taskElement = document.querySelector(`.task-to-do[data-id="${id}"]`);

  let Editedmodal = document.querySelector("#edit-modal");
  let EditedInputTask = document.querySelector("#edit-task");
  let EditedInputDate = document.querySelector("#edit-duedate");

  EditedObject = {
    EditTask: taskArray[taskIndex].task,
    Editdate: taskArray[taskIndex].date
  }



  Editedmodal.style.display = "grid";
  /*Submit Edited task Form*/
  EditedsubmitForm.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

    EditedInputTask.value = EditedObject.editTask;
    EditedInputDate.value = EditedObject.Editdate;
    /*Form Validaion*/
    if (!EditedInputTask.value) {
      EditedInputNoTask.style.display = "block";
      EditedInputTask.style.marginTop = "-1em";
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        EditedInputNoTask.style.display = "none";
        EditedInputTask.style.marginTop = "0";
      }, 3000);
    }

    if (!EditedInputDate.value) {
      EditedInputNoDate.style.display = "block";
      EditedInputDate.style.marginTop = "-1em";

      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        EditedInputNoDate.style.display = "none";
        EditedInputDate.style.marginTop = "0";
      }, 3000);
    } else {
      Editedmodal.style.display = "none";
      EditedInputTask.value = "";
      EditedInputDate.value = "";
    }

    taskArray[taskIndex].task = EditedInputTask.value;
    taskArray[taskIndex].date = EditedInputDate.value;


    taskElement.querySelector("#list-item-date").textContent = `Due: ${taskArray[taskIndex].date}`;
    taskElement.querySelector("#list-item-task").textContent = taskArray[taskIndex].task;
    
    renderTask();
    storeTaskArrayLocally();
    

    console.log(EditedObject)

  });


When you step through the code using a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  Can you update this to a [mcve] as a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem, and indicate specifically how you are observing that problem?

Hi there, I added a link to code pen of a sample of the issue I am running into
https://codepen.io/Blazeinferno92/pen/GRLxEpw
